# NSButton loses blue highlight effect when setting an Alternate image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, macos, nsbutton

When I use a NSButton with style 'Round Rect', type 'Toggle' and an image, the image and title will be nicely rendered in blue, when the State is set to On.

However, when I also add an alternate image, this highlight effect is gone.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

I want to achieve the same effect as the small tab bar icons on top of the Inspector in Xcode: blue when selected, using an alternate image (slightly bolder), black when not selected, using the default image.

Comment: Please add any code you have tried so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The blue highlight effect can be achieved without any code, just by using the settings mentioned in my first line. This effect disappears as soon as I set an alternate image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The system only transforms your template to apply the visual highlight if you don't supply your own alternate (active / lit / on) version.

Comment: I have accidentally found the documentation from Apple that proves the above answer, while looking for another 'challenge', on [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/), stating '_You may note that it isn't possible to both use a distinct piece of art as an alternateImage on a button or segmented control and also get the blue glow. This may be somewhat limiting, but should tend to make sure this effect is only used when appropriate._'.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a more elegant solution, I'm using this workaround:

```
-(IBAction)handleClick:(id)sender
{
    NSButton *button = sender;
    button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:[button.identifier stringByAppendingString:button.state == NSOnState ? @"On" : @""]];
}
```

I toggle in code between the standard image and the alternate image, using the identifier of the control as a base name for the image. A bit ugly, but it works. The image on the button is now blue highlighted while showing the (slightly bolder) alternate image, when in 'On' state.

Answer (score 0):

To NOT use an alternate image and get an NSButton (macOS 10.13) with Blue Tint when ON and not when OFF like some of the buttons in Xcode toolbar, I had to do the following:

1. png in asset catalog with transparent background and white line drawing.
2. png in asset catalog set to render as "template" (see right sidebar).
3. Set only 1 image. Do not use an alternate image or it no worky.
4. bezelstyle = NSTexturedRoundedBezelStyle.
5. buttontType = NSToggleButton.

I also change controlTint in the button action handler for state.

Comment: The question is not about changing the color when selecting (should work according your  steps, however step 6 is not needed when you set the state to ON), but about changing the color AND changing the image when selecting the button. My current solution implies changing the image in code instead of using the alternate image setting.

Comment: Your correct state is not required to be set, I've edited it. However one could (and I did) interpret this question to mean how do I get the blue highlighted effect when state changes.